# Arrange ipywidgets with interactive - Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, interactive, ipywidgets

I am trying to put together a `Dropdown` widget with `interactive` insise a `VBox` but I am facing an issue I am not sure how to solve. Any idea what is the cause here?

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

listw = widgets.Dropdown(options=(['Option 1']), description='Test')    
save_crop_sizes=widgets.interact.options(manual=True, manual_name="Save Crop Sizes")
    
outputwi = widgets.VBox([listw, save_crop_sizes])

TraitError: The 'children' trait of a VBox instance contains an Instance of a TypedTuple which expected a Widget, not the _InteractFactory at '0x1cb35a86ac8'.
```

Comment: What function are you trying to get your widgets to `interact` with? It doesn't appear the in the example.